# sort en un subdocumento en nodejs y mongobd

Tags: javascript, nodejs, api, mongodb, backend

Hola necesito ayuda en como puedo ordenar por edad el contenido de un subdocumento tengo algo asi:

```js
 "usuario": {
      "_id": "32022",
      "nombre": "juan",
         "comentarios": 
         [{
           "contenido": "contenido comentario",
           "edad":22
         },
         {
          "contenido": "contenido comentario",
          "edad":30
         },
         {
         "contenido": "contenido comentario",
         "edad"14
         }]
}
```

en mi controlador tengo este metodo que me hace me devuelve la informacion de ese usuario con sus comentarios, pero quiero ordenar esos comentarios por edad, como puedo hacerlo ya que es un subdocumento?

```js
var usuarioId = req.params.id;

        Usuario.findById(usuarioId).exec((err, usuario) => {

            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'error en la peticion'
                });
            }
            if (!usuario) {
                return res.status(404).send({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'No existe usuario'

                });
            } else {

                return res.status(200).send({
                    status: 'success',
                    usuario

                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Para no agregar complejidad a tu codigo lo puedes hacer después de recibir tus datos con esta linea `Usuario.comentarios.sort((a, b)=> a.edad > b.edad?1:-1 )`

De esta manera:

```
var usuarioId = req.params.id;

        Usuario.findById(usuarioId).exec((err, usuario) => {

            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'error en la peticion'
                });
            }
            if (!usuario) {
                return res.status(404).send({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'No existe usuario'

                });
            } else {

                //Aqui viene el truco
                Usuario.comentarios.sort((a, b)=> a.edad > b.edad?1:-1 )



                return res.status(200).send({
                    status: 'success',
                    usuario

                });
            }
        });
```